# How can i test redux .subscribe()

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, redux, jestjs

In my code, that i want to test, has store.subscribe() function, and i dont know, how can i test it.

```
test('should call console.log inside subscribe fn', async () => {
  const store = configureStore(initialState);
  store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState())); // console.log was not called

  await wait(100);
})
```

And in my code

```
// index.ts

export const store = createStore();
store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState())); // how can i test it in jest?
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to test the `subscriber` function, then you can trigger it through dispatch action. Assert the state after each action is dispatched.

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

test('should call console.log inside subscribe fn', async () => {
  expect.assertions(1);
  const store = configureStore({ reducer: (state = 'test state') => state });
  store.subscribe(() => {
    expect(store.getState()).toEqual('test state');
  });
  store.dispatch({ type: '' });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS   redux-toolkit-example  packages/redux-toolkit-example/stackoverflow/69845750/index.test.ts
  ✓ should call console.log inside subscribe fn (4 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.869 s
```

Comment: It can works in test. But how can i test this example?.

```
const a = () => {
  store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()))
}
```

Comment: @polRk Use `jest.spyOn(console, 'log')` to add spy on `console.log` method, assert it to be called with the whole state after dispatching an action.

Comment: It is not working